# access to the ropsten history

Tags: ropsten

Ropsten testnet stopped creating blocks 17 days ago and infura RPC endpoint (https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/) no longer work (always answer "*Network decommissioned*").
Is there a way to connect to a node or kind of backup server (using web3.js ideally) so I can still read data stored by a past contact ?

Comment: Since the network is deprecated it is likely the only remaining option is to run a previous version of geth to download data.

Answer (score 1):

You can still read the data stored by a past contract and transactions in ropsten testnet. However, note that the explorer will eventually be sunset:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

Answer (score 0):

This site https://chainlist.org hepl me to find the answer ("https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_ropsten" online at this time, slow but it works :) )

Answer (score 0):

The Ropsten testnet explorer has been discontinued and set to read-only on October 5th, 2022.
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
All data is saved and you can read any transactions on ropsten or on rinkeby